# set ResultSet Column Header

Tags: java

Here is my JAVA Code

```
db.Connect();
String_Query = "Select * from some_table";
pst=getConnection().prepareStatement(String_Query);
rs=pst.executeQuery();
/*

change column names . . .

*/
db.close();
```

I Wanna Change ResultSet Column Names. for example if the first column name is "id", I would like to change it into "myText". I wanna change all column names into my favorite vales and then assign that ResultSet into a jTable.(i don't want to change column names in jTable).

Any Help is Appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You ca do this in the SQL with:

```
SELECT id AS 'myText' FROM some_table;
```